# Counting vowels while removing them from a string

Tags: python, string

```
s=input("Enter a string:")
length=len(s)
i=0
c=0
while i<length:
    if (s[i]=='a' or s[i]=='e' or s[i]=='i' or s[i]=='o' or s[i]=='u'):
        s=s.replace(s[i], ' ')
        c=c+1
    i+=1
print(s+str(c))
```

I have to remove the vowels from a string and then print it along with its vowel count. If I enter `"umbrella"`, I get the output `"mbr ll 3"`.
I want to get `"mbrll3"`. What else can I add to my code to get the correct output?

Comment: note: if you have a certain vowel more than once, your count will be incorrect, because `s.replace` replaces all occurrences in the string.

Comment: @HeapOverflow my bad. use the code as is and add a replace inside the print `print(s.replace(' ', '')+str(c))` to print `mbrll3`

Answer (score 3):

You can filter the word into a new list, keeping the count as you go.

```
>>> s=input("Enter a string:")
Enter a string:umbrella
>>> count = 0
>>> filtered = []
>>> for c in s:
...     if c in "aeiou":
...             count += 1
...     else:
...             filtered.append(c)
... 
>>> newstr = "".join(filtered)
>>> print("{}{}".format(newstr, count))
mbrll3
>>>
```

Come to think of it, this could be done more compactly simply by comparing the lengths of the before and after strings.

```
s=input("Enter a string:")
newstr = "".join(c for c in s if c not in "aeiou")
print("{}{}".format(newstr, len(s)-len(newstr)))
```

Comment: Well thanks a lot but..I have no idea how filter fuction and filter append works as I am very new to coding. I just wanted to solve this problem with the knowledge I have.